# React native android custom component UI crashes with FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to follow the steps specified in [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html)

after some struggle I got my android side code compile but no matter what propTypes I put in the js file I always get the following crashes:

> Error: Can\'t find variable: PropTypes\n stack: \n   
>   index.android.bun…:52892\n  require    index.android.bun…:254\n 
>     index.android.bun…:1429\n  require
>   index.android.bun…:254\n  require    index.android.bun…:200\n 
>     global code@index…:52898\n URL: index.android.bundle\n
>   line: 52892\n message: Can\'t find variable: PropTypes'

My js code looks like this:

```
var { requireNativeComponent } = require('react-native');

var icon = {   
    name: 'IconTextView',   
    propTypes: {
      fontFamily: PropTypes.string   
    },
};

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTIconTextView', icon);
```

Am I missing anything here? Can someone point me to a working example?

#### SOLVED:

Finally I got my javascript side working with the following code:

```
var { requireNativeComponent } = require('react-native');
var React = require('react-native');

var icon = {
  name: 'IconTextView',
  propTypes: {
    fontFamily: React.PropTypes.string,
    scaleX:     React.PropTypes.number,
    scaleY:     React.PropTypes.number,
    translateX: React.PropTypes.number,
    translateY: React.PropTypes.number,
    rotation:   React.PropTypes.number,
    opacity:    React.PropTypes.number,
    backgroundColor: React.PropTypes.number,
  },
};

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTIconTextView', icon);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Yes I do. You need to require react as well. Please see the code segment I attached.

Answer (score 0):

For people coming to this hhread because of the **MYSTERIOUS** `mqt_native_modules` error in React Native read on:

I'm posting to let you know that this bug is caused by a limitation  to the number of subviews on old Android phones. (~16-20 Views MAX).

See those 2 issues: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5404 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7416.

Apparently it has been fixed on [React 27.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.27.0-rc), so lets wait for that.